# How to I access deeper xdocument nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<Invoice_Ack>
    <Invoices>
        <Invoice>
            <Invoice_Number>123456</Invoice_Number>
            <Status>Rejected</Status>
            <Detail_Errors>
                <Detail_Error>
                    <ErrorID>0001</ErrorID>
                    <ErrorMessage>This is the error message</ErrorMessage>
                </Detail_Error>
                <Detail_Error>
                    <ErrorID>0502</ErrorID>
                    <ErrorMessage>This is another error message</ErrorMessage>
                </Detail_Error>
            </Detail_Errors>
        </Invoice>
    </Invoices>
</Invoice_Ack>
```

I can access the "Invoice_Number" and "Status" nodes with the following code, but I'm not sure how to also grab the "ErrorMessage" node. Here's what I have:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);

foreach(var invoice in doc.Descendants("Invoice"))
{
    string status = invoice.Element("Status").Value;
    string invoicenum = invoice.Element("Invoice_Number").Value;
}
```

But how do I get ErrorMessage? I tried

```
string error = invoice.Element("Detail_Errors").Element("Detail_Error").Element("ErrorMessage").Value;
```

But that gives me a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

How else can this be done? Thank you!!

Comment: Your sample XML is invalid - it starts an `<Invoice>` element, but ends it as `</Invoices>`. Please give us a short but *complete and valid* example of both the XML and the code.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo .. I've updated it. The first <Invoice> should have been <Invoices>.

Comment: Your code works fine for the XML provided.

Comment: It was failing as some Detail_Errors were blank and didn't contain the Detail_Error node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've given works for the XML you've given. I suspect you've actually got an invoice which doesn't *have* any errors - and that's what's wrong.

You should loop over the errors:

```
foreach (var error in invoice.Elements("Detail_Errors").Elements("Detail_Error"))
{
    var id = error.Element("ErrorID").Value;
    var message = error.Element("ErrorMessage").Value;
    // Do whatever you want with the ID and message
}
```

Note the use of `Elements("Detail_Errors")` here - if there's *always* exactly one `Detail_Errors` element (possibly with no child elements), you could just use `Element("Detail_Errors")` but the code I've given will work even if there are *no* `Detail_Errors` elements.

Comment: that worked! thank you!!!! and you were right about running into an invoice without an error .. that's what I was getting stuck on. Also, in your above code I had to change .Element("Detail_Error") to .Elements("Detail_Error") as the Detail_Error node doesn't exist if there are no Detail_Errors. At least that's why I think I had to change it .. I'm still learning about Element vs Elements.